# dropdown ajax field not save fileds on databasse

Tags: 7, ajax, database

I am trying to create my own module and I'm having trouble saving information in the database.

in fact, the values are stored in the database, but the first value of the array (String) (violin)

If I try to change, everything seems to work fine, but when I save the node, see again in the database (String) (violin)

this is my contactos_clientes.install

```
<?php      
  function contactos_clientes_field_schema($field) {



       switch ($field['type']) {
        case 'contactos_clientes':
          $columns = array(
            'dropdown_first' => array(
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'length' => '65',
              'not null' => FALSE
            ),
            'dropdown_second' => array(
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'length' => '65',
              'not null' => FALSE
            ),
          );
          break;
      }

      return array('columns' => $columns);
    }
?>
```

and this is my contactos_clientes.module

```
<?php
function contactos_clientes_field_info() {
  return array(
    'contactos_clientes'    => array(
      'label'             => t('contactos_clientes'),
      'description'       => t('Sugiere Contactos para clientes'),
      'default_widget'    => 'contactos_clientes',
      'default_formatter' => 'contactos_clientes',
    ),
  );
}

function contactos_clientes_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'contactos_clientes' => array(
      'label' => t('Text fields'),
      'field types' => array('contactos_clientes'),
    ),
  );
}

function contactos_clientes_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'contactos_clientes':
        $options_first = _ajax_example_get_first_dropdown_options();
        $selected = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first'] : key($options_first);
        $form['dropdown_first'] = array(
          '#type' => 'select',
          '#title' => 'Instrument Type',
          '#options' => $options_first,
          '#default_value' => $selected,
          '#required'      => $element['#required'],
          '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
          ),
        );
        $form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $options_first[$selected] . ' ' . t('Instruments'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($selected),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
  );

      break;
  }

  return $element;
}
function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['dropdown_second'];
}

function contactos_clientes_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'contactos_clientes':
      if(empty($item['value'])) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      break;
  }

  return FALSE;
}

function _ajax_example_get_first_dropdown_options() {
  // drupal_map_assoc() just makes an array('String' => 'String'...).
  return drupal_map_assoc(
    array(
      t('String'),
      t('Woodwind'),
      t('Brass'),
      t('Percussion'),
    )
  );
}
function _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    t('String') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Violin'),
        t('Viola'),
        t('Cello'),
        t('Double Bass'),
      )
    ),
    t('Woodwind') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Flute'),
        t('Clarinet'),
        t('Oboe'),
        t('Bassoon'),
      )
    ),
    t('Brass') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Trumpet'),
        t('Trombone'),
        t('French Horn'),
        t('Euphonium'),
      )
    ),
    t('Percussion') => drupal_map_assoc(
      array(
        t('Bass Drum'),
        t('Timpani'),
        t('Snare Drum'),
        t('Tambourine'),
      )
    ),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
}




?>
```

What am I doing wrong? thank you.